# C Segment Fault on char** Array

Tags: c, string, parsing, pointers, strsep

I am unsure why I am receiving a segmentation fault when my program hits the first `if` statement.

This is a method in a simpleShell program that's sole purpose is parsing stdin input stored in `cmd` and parse by whitespace into separate arguments in `args`

It will never print the `if` statement

```
void parseCmd(char* cmd, char** args)
{       
    int i;


    printf("----------> Parsed here \n");
    for(i = 0; i < MAX_LINE; i++) {
        args[i] = strsep(&cmd, " ");

        if (args[i][0] == '-') {
            printf("I was here... \n");
        }


        if(args[i] == NULL) break;
    }
}
```

Comment: `char **` is **no** array!

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing two obvious NULL checks.

1. Check for NULL against `args`
2. Check for NULL in `strsep()` return value.

Otherwise, you may very well attempt a NULL pointer deference in either case which results in [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: I cant believe i missed that, ofc args will be null on newline, just had to move the if statement up, thanks!